# Unable to install Xcode using dmg file downloaded from Apple.com

Tags: install, xcode

I am trying to install Xcode 7.1 on OS X 10.10.5 using the dmg file downloaded from Apple. However, I have tried several times and the install always stopped at "Calculating size" when I dragged the icon to the Application folder. I waited for 2 hours and nothing happened. How can I install Xcode using the the dmg file?

My MacBook Air wireless adapter is damaged so I am unable to update Xcode from Mac App Store — the only way I can get Xcode is to download that dmg file.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing this you need to delete the unfinished downloads and run this link in browser , which i mentioned below.
You can find the DMGs for Xcode and other development tools on https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ (requires Apple ID to login).
Link for Xcode [7.0.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1.1/Xcode_7.1.1.dmg) you can try this link.
Hope this will help.

Comment: I can download. It is completed. I just can't install the dmg file to the app folder.

Comment: you must clear the cache of previously download Xcode for that , go to application folder delete the Xcode and now try to install it again .

Comment: what do you mean clear the cache of previously download XCode? Did I miss something? I just drag the unfinished XCode installed APP to the trash and empty the bin. That's what I did, every time.

Comment: yeah.. while you being clicking on .dmg file corresponding app will be copy the some file into the application folder . so that things will come under package contents. So you just need to delete that Xcode fromApplication folder. hope it will work

Comment: but it didn't work. Every time I cleaned things up. But Every new install is stuck at "Calculating size". I have tried 7.2.1 and 7.1.1. Both of them failed to install. It's so strange.

Comment: Try clearing your cache, and restart the download from the app store. You can use third-party apps or enter this command in your terminal:

rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/com.apple.appstore"